# Transform raw atomic coordinate data into SDF file

Tags: molecular-structure, cheminformatics

I have raw data of the atom types and their coordinates. For example, water molecule is:

```
O -0.034 0.977 0.007
H 0.064 0.020 0.001
H 0.871 1.300 0.0006
```

Here, I would like to transform this atomic coordinate data into SDF file. How can I do it with a software or library such as RDKit?

Comment: You can use openbabel for this. https://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 4):

Your work ahead requires two steps

- completion of the file to be a valid .xyz file
- transformation of the .xyz into a .sdf file, a task for which [openbabel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel) already is one of the tools suitable (in my experience, easier to set up than RDKit facing the IT department)

For the first one, the snippet shared looks like the block about atomic coordinates in a .xyz file.  To be syntactically complete, two leading lines are missing: one about the total number of atoms (an integer number), and one which either remains blank empty, or optionally may carry a comment.  In your case, the minimal form of your snippet to pass the next step hence would be a file

```
3

O -0.034 0.977 0.007
H 0.064 0.020 0.001
H 0.871 1.300 0.0006
```

You do not share the origin of the snippet, nor the operating system of the computer used.  Possibly, the quantum chemical software used to provide you with said geometry offers the export of the result as a complete .xyz file which already contains the number of atoms.  (Else, because this type of programs often run in Linux/Unix, `wc -l my_file.txt` will report the number of lines in file `my_file` so that you don't have to manually count the lines in your original snippet either.)

---

The second step is the transformation into a format richer in information, .sdf.  It is richer than .xyz because *in addition* to the atomic coordinates (as provided by the .xyz) there is a *chemical table*.  This is to report which atoms are connected with each other, the assigned nature of the bond (bond order single, double, etc.), information about stereochemistry (CIP rules about *R* vs *S*, or *E* vs *Z* configuration), assignment of charges, etc.  And similar as the .xyz, additional information optionally may be provided in comment-like entries.  The English edition of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#SDF) has a dedicated entry, including a permanent link to .pdf [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210219065450/https://discover.3ds.com/sites/default/files/2020-08/biovia_ctfileformats_2020.pdf) which specifies the .sdf formats in greater detail.

Assuming the above, now already complete .xyz file was saved as file `example.xyz`, and openbabel successfully installed, the command on the command line would be

```shell
obabel example.xyz -O output.sdf
```

to write a .sdf (by default in version V2000) of name `output.sdf` in the pattern of

```
example.xyz
 OpenBabelDDMMYYhhmmXX

  3  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -0.0340    0.9770    0.0070 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0640    0.0200    0.0010 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.8710    1.3000    0.0006 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  1  1  0  0  0  0
  3  1  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
```

This record states the name of the file initially read, followed by the creator of the new file and a time stamp.  After setting the ground for the information to follow, there are the atoms and their coordinates; followed by said now additional block of chemical information.

Side note:  By default, openbabel provides the conversion into .sdf (V2000).  Depending on your wanted use down the road, you might want to use the more recent dialect of .sdf (V3000).  You can obtain this by a conversion with the additional `-x3` flag, i.e.

```shell
obabel example.xyz -O output.sdf -x3
```

to yield a record in pattern of

```
example.xyz
 OpenBabelDDMMYYhhmmXX

  0  0  0     0  0            999 V3000
M  V30 BEGIN CTAB
M  V30 COUNTS 3 2 0 0 0
M  V30 BEGIN ATOM
M  V30 1 O -0.034 0.977 0.007 0
M  V30 2 H 0.064 0.02 0.001 0
M  V30 3 H 0.871 1.3 0.0006 0
M  V30 END ATOM
M  V30 BEGIN BOND
M  V30 1 1 3 1
M  V30 2 1 2 1
M  V30 END BOND
M  V30 END CTAB
M  END
$$$$
```

instead (see the program's documentation [here](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/MDL_MOL_format.html)).  This format dialect becomes advantageous to you if extended stereochemistry features e.g., to describe racemates and diastereomeric mixtures are needed (instead of either (*R*)- or (*S*)-mandelic acid, you describe both in one model) in larger sets of data* and databases, rather than to depict the conformation of a specific molecular structure only.  Contemporary viewers (e.g. [avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/), [Jmol](https://jmol.sourceforge.net/)) are ready to display either .sdf (V2000), or .sdf (V3000).

* Because a .sdf can serve as a container for multiple, individually separate structure descriptions.